# NodeJS throws the following error: "Error: Cannot find module 'exit'"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am getting the following error from my CI server:

```
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'exit'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/go/node_modules/grunt-legacy-util/index.js:28:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

I am not sure what the cause of this error is. Can someone please help?

Here are the commands I use:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli

npm install

grunt karma
```

Comment: Have you tried installing the `exit` module? If so, does that fix it?

Comment: Hi @Chev Do I need to install this module globally or locally?

Comment: I tried installing the `exit` module both globally and locally. To no avail... I still get the same error message.

Comment: do npm install exit. This will install exit module. To confirm whether this module is installed properly or not, you can check node_modules folder if it exists there or not.

Comment: It turned out that there was an issue with my CI's cache. Clearing the cache sorted the issue.

Comment: Glad you got it working :)

Comment: For me it was something to do with my current NPM version. I reverted to v18.2.0 with NVM and that resolved the issue.